# Adding a script file that reads @TempData in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Just wondering if there is a way to add a

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/defaultFoo")
```

to a view, that will accept @TempData being passed to the view from the controller.

I am using [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) to setup messages for save and delete operations on the index view.
I am setting the script to handle that inside the view like so

```
$(function () {
        toastr.options = {
            "positionClass": "toast-top-left",
        }

        var SaveMsg = "@TempData["SaveMsg"]";
        var DelMsg = "@TempData["DelMsg"]";

        if (SaveMsg != "") {
            toastr.info(SaveMsg,"Saved")
        }

        if (DelMsg != "") {
            toastr.warning(DelMsg,"Deleted")
        }
    });
```

It works fine, but i would like to just add a script file that would then call this, because i have this same script on about 5 views, and probably will add it to a few more. So instead of writing the script every time in the view i just want to call a bundle to handle it

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myDefaultMsgBundle")
```

Comment: No. Razor does not parse external script files. The actual variables would need to be declared in the main view.

Comment: That suxs. I might try something with local storage then ... somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to a partial view in your shared views folder, then anywhere you need it, emit it using

```
@Html.Partial("_your toastr view")
```

Easier than trying to pass variables around to external files etc